# Why aren't divs full height in a vertical flexbox?

Tags: html, css

Consider the following code snippet:

```html
<style>
.v {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}
.e {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
.q {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 500px;
}
</style>
<div class="q">
  <div class="v">
      <div class="e">hello1</div>
      <div class="e">hello2</div>
      <div class="e">hello1</div>
      <div class="e">hello1</div>
      <div class="e">hello2</div>
      <div class="e">hello1</div>
      <div class="e">hello2</div>
      <div class="e">hello1</div>
      <div class="e">hello2</div>
      <div class="e">hello1</div>
      <div class="e">hello2</div>
      <div class="e">hello1</div>
      <div class="e">hello2</div>
      <div class="e">hello1</div>
      <div class="e">hello2</div>
  </div>
<div>
```

The divs are not full height, despite having `height: 100px`.
How would I make the divs be full height?

Note, this snippet looks different locally, but the issue is the same (the divs are not full height).

Comment: To vertically stack `div`s you won't need a `display: flex;` as the default `display: block;` will do just that. Should you want to use `flex` and `fiex-direction: column`, however, you'd need to set the `flex-basis: 100px` with `flex-shrink: 0;`.

Comment: all you need is to add flex-shrink:0 to them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

flex-direction: column will prevent the divs from taking up full space
You can use min-height instead of height. so that the div e will have min height all time.

```
.e {
    min-height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change this behavior, by assigng your wrapped container a `min-width`.

```css
    .v {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        min-height: 50%; /* this line ! for example 50% or 100% etc. */
    }
```

```html
<style>
.v {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    min-height: 100%; 
}
.e {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
.q {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 500px;
}
</style>
<div class="q">
  <div class="v">
      <div class="e">hello1</div>
      <div class="e">hello2</div>
      <div class="e">hello1</div>
      <div class="e">hello1</div>
      <div class="e">hello2</div>
      <div class="e">hello1</div>
      <div class="e">hello2</div>
      <div class="e">hello1</div>
      <div class="e">hello2</div>
      <div class="e">hello1</div>
      <div class="e">hello2</div>
      <div class="e">hello1</div>
      <div class="e">hello2</div>
      <div class="e">hello1</div>
      <div class="e">hello2</div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `flex-direction: column`, so the dimension is changed. That means, you have to set the `width` to 100% or 100px (depends on what you really want) and also set `min-width`.

Comment: Wow, removing the flex-box worked. Could you explain why `flex-direction: column` is preventing the divs from taking up full space?

Comment: And what specific thing should I set to `100px`? (thanks by the way, I was stuck on this for a while!)

Comment: Actually, if you just want a stacking div, you don't need to set the div as flex-box. Also, you can learn more about flexbox here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ . Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you set `500px` for `.q` and `height: 100%` for `.v` that will make flexbox `.v` use it as an anchor point for spreading children's element sizes (this is the behavior of flexbox). If you try to add more `div` for your testing, they won't ever and never go out of your fixed height `500px`

This is how they communicate:

V: I have 100% height, where could I get a height reference for 100%?

P: You can take mine, because I have 500px height

E: Why you don't take mine, V?

V: Nah, I trust my parent elements

If you remove `height: 500px` in `.q`, it will work as you expected

```
.v {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}
.e {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
.q {
    overflow: auto; /*Modified it as auto or you also can remove it*/
}
```

Another possible fix, you can remove `height: 100%` in `.v` as it won't take `.q` as a height reference again.

```
.v {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.e {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
.q {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Another side note, flexbox by default is using `flex-direction: row;`, and usually, we use `flex-direction: column;` for mobile responsive purposes. In your case, if it's only for desktop, you can remove flexbox, by default, it will render row-based div

```
.v {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}
.e {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
.q {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 500px;
}
```